# Bazel test fails while building SyntaxNet on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I have encountered a problem while building the SyntaXnet. I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 17.10, was following the 'manual installation' guide here: [SyntaxNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet). I successfully installed all of the packages listed there,  additionally I've installed 5th version of gcc and added it as an alternative, because tensorflow doesn't support next versions (at least it said so). Configured tensorflow (chose 'default' or 'no' for everything) and moved on to the test which failed with this error:

```
ERROR: /home/double/.cache/bazel/_bazel_double /43ab8fb5dff609b6b3ab4eb2438eb6cc/external/protobuf_archive/BUILD:133:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf_archive//:protobuf' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command 
(cd /home/double/.cache/bazel/_bazel_double/43ab8fb5dff609b6b3ab4eb2438eb6cc/execroot/__main__ && \
exec env - \
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/double/bin:/home/double/bin \
PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
/usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-   
pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g0 '-std=c++0x' -g0 -MD -MF bazel-out/host/bin/external
/protobuf_archive/_objs/protobuf/external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/host/bin/external
/protobuf_archive/_objs/protobuf/external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/json_stream_parser.o' -iquote external/protobuf_archive -iquote 
bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/protobuf_archive -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/protobuf_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/host/genfiles/external
/protobuf_archive/src -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -DHAVE_PTHREAD -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare 
-Wno-unused-function -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/util/internal
/json_stream_parser.cc -o bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/_objs/protobuf/external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/util/internal   /json_stream_parser.o).
```

It's probably related to the faulty installation of gcc, but I can't understand how to fix it. I can't find this particular problem in the github issues or here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is there anything else to the error message, like what specifically did `gcc` fail to do? Also, which version of Bazel are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.5.4 as it asks for in the guide. This error has a lot of text, but this is a piece : 
`In file included from external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc:38:0:
external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.h: In static member function 'static bool google::protobuf::MathLimits<float>::IsFinite(google::protobuf::MathLimits<float>::Type)':
external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/stubs/mathlimits.h:285:1: error: '__builtin_isinf_sign' is not a member of 'std'
 DECL_FP_LIMITS(float, FLT)`.

Comment: 0.5.4 is very old, it's probably the minimum version anything around TensorFlow still supports. Try updating to the latest version, 0.10.0, and see if that works.

Comment: @László, I've installed it, cleaned bazel, but, unfortunately, the same error occurs.